# How do I exclude directories when using git log?

Tags: git, awk

**Aim**

I would like to know the amount of lines changed in a particular repository over a period of time and print this into a simple text file. However, when I run the code below I receive an error that I'm not sure how to solve.

**The code**

```
git log --stat --since="2015-01-01" --until="2015-11-16" `find . \( ! -path "*[PATH]*" -a ! -path "*[PATH2]*" \)` | awk -F',' "/files? changed/ {
    files += \$1
    insertions += \$2
    deletions += \$3
    destination = \"$DESTINATION\"}

END {
    print \"Files Changed: \" files > destination
    print \"Insertions: \" insertions > destination
    print \"Deletions: \" deletions > destination
    print \"Lines changed: \" insertions + deletions > destination}"
```

**The error**

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '[PATH]': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
awk: cmd. line:7: fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

**Other useful information**

- The version of Git used is 1.7.1. Therefore I cannot use this: --oneline --format=%s -- . ":(exclude)[PATH]"
- I know this code works when I do not try to exclude directories.
- I also know that the "find" works correctly when run separately.

**Question**

Could someone please help me understand what I've done wrong or provide a better way of excluding multiple directories?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought: Do any of the files returned by the `find` have spaces anywhere (path or  filename)? Because that back-ticked `find` will mess up in that case.

Comment: No, good idea Jeff but unfortunately they don't. I've just checked through them,

Comment: Anyone else got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error message written by **git** tells how to fix the error. The problem is that, sometimes, **git** is unable to tell if the first argument it is given is a path or a revision. The `--` can be used to disambiguate arguments.

Asides from this, there is a few other minor problems in your code. The shell also understands simple quotes, where variables are not expanded. You definitely should write your **awk** script in simple quotes, as it prevents clumsy escape sequences to spam your code.

```
git log --stat --since='2015-01-01' --until='2015-11-16' $(find . \( ! -path '*[PATH]*' -a ! -path '*[PATH2]*' \)) | awk -F',' '
/files? changed/ {
  files += $1
  insertions += $2
  deletions += $3
}

END {
  print "Files Changed: " files
  print "Insertions: " insertions
  print "Deletions: " deletions
  print "Lines changed: " insertions + deletions
}' > "${DESTINATION}"
```

Also, if you are writing output to only one file, it is easier to let **awk** write its report to *stdout* and redirect it to the file you want, rather than doing output redirections in **awk** itself.